# UIWebview taking too much of time to load html content in iOS 7

Tags: ios, mathjax

Uiwebview taking huge amount of time to load html content in iOS 7. The html content has mathjax library.

Its working good in iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.1.

Can you please help me how to fix this issue?

I am using loadRequest method to load html content into UIWebView.

Thanks,
Rahman

Comment: Probably gonna need to show relevant code.

Comment: @Rahman..did you find any solution to your problem? I am facing same issue even though I have saved complete MathJax library into my application bundle. It takes almost 7-8 seconds to type mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.  After the update to iOS 7, the loadRequest takes about 10 seconds (with iOS 6 less than a second).

My code is like :

```
NSString *whichWiki = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
NSString *keyword = @"universe";
NSString *siteURLWiki  =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",whichWiki, keyword];
[webv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURLWiki]]];
```

I tried 2 resolutions I found in Google:

```
self.webv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone; // Resolution 1 

self.webv.suppressesIncrementalRendering = YES; // Resolution 2
```

but with results of no effects.

Strangely, I have this problem with URL of Wikipedia but NOT WITH URL of Google.  I can get URLs of Google search results less than a second.

What's the difference between Wikipedia and Google ???

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked the **phone numbers detection** on UIWebView from Storyboard. It works for me.